# Magento 2.3.3 tab jumping on Top

Tags: magento2

I have followed Mage documentation from [Magento official website](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_tabs.html) on clicking it's jumping on top:
I am using 2.3.3, any way to stop jumping?

```
<div class="product data items"
     data-mage-init='{"mage/tabs": {"openedState": "active", "animate": {"duration": 100}, "active": 1, "disabled": [2], "disabledState": "disabled"}}'>
    <div class="item title" data-role="collapsible">
        <a class="switch" data-toggle="trigger" href="#tab-cars">Cars</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-cars" class="item content" data-role="content">Cars content</div>

    <div class="item title" data-role="collapsible">
        <a class="switch" data-toggle="trigger" href="#tab-movies">Movies</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-movies" class="item content" data-role="content">Movies content</div>

    <div class="item title" data-role="collapsible">
        <a class="switch" data-toggle="trigger" href="#tab-music">Music</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-music" class="item content" data-role="content">Music Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Now, this functionality is embedded inside `lib/web/mage/collapsible.js`.
And to disable scrolling and transfer this possibility to scroll to the initialization `options` need to create `mixin` for this `jQuery` widget.

`app/design/frontend/<VendorName>/<ThemeName>/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/collapsible': {
                'js/mage/collapsible-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`app/design/frontend/<VendorName>/<ThemeName>/web/js/mage/collapsible-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
], function ($) {

    var hideProps = {},
        showProps = {};

    hideProps.height =  'hide';
    showProps.height =  'show';

    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.collapsible', widget, {
            options: {
                scrollTo: false
            },

            _create: function () {
                this.storage = $.localStorage;
                this.icons = false;

                if (typeof this.options.icons === 'string') {
                    this.options.icons = $.parseJSON(this.options.icons);
                }

                this._processPanels();
                this._processState();
                this._refresh();

                if (this.options.icons.header && this.options.icons.activeHeader) {
                    this._createIcons();
                    this.icons = true;
                }

                if (this.options.scrollTo) {
                    this.element.on('dimensionsChanged', function (e) {
                        if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
                            this._scrollToTopIfVisible(e.target);
                        }
                    }.bind(this));
                }

                this._bind('click');
                this._trigger('created');
            },
        });

        return $.mage.collapsible;
    };
});
```

UPD: that was fixed in `Magento 2.3.4` ([Pull Request](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/adda871f81d3eb0053551c776da7149cceb42421#diff-86f8bae6acef05c38ed1f934367400d0))

Comment: I will try and let you know if this solution works for anyone please comment here.

Comment: @Volodymyr, I am experiencing the same issue and tried your method above, issue is resolved but all other collapsible sections such as discount code, summary section on cart, checkout page right nav secton etc. are stopped clicking after this implementation. Please help me on this.

Comment: @Arunendra - did you get any final solution on this. please help me.

Comment: @KamleshYaduwanshi If you didn't change the default behavior it should work fine. Tested on the Magento 2.3.3 (fresh install).

Comment: @KamleshYaduwanshi I have downgraded its version to 2.3.2 as I was in a hurry.

Comment: @VolodymyrLisniak fix is working great thank you very much.

Comment: @Volodymyr Lisniak  thank you

Comment: config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/collapsible': {
                'Namespace_ModuleName/js/mage/collapsible-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Namespace_ModuleName in the mixin after that it will work !

Comment: @ManishGoswami It is a global file. You don't need to put it in a specific module.

Comment: Hi @VolodymyrLisniak we are facing same issue in the Magento2.3.5 P2 B2B followed same steps not working could you please advise me thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this have been fixed [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/23862/files). Worked for us. This will still trigger scrolling but only if the extended content extends beyond the bottom of the viewport. This solution has been merged to Magento repo by their team and this issue will be solved in next release.

[Same issue on github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25053). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is a new option added to magento 2.3.3

to remove it  use this patch

create a file in your main dir

**revert_scrolltop.patch**

add this content to file

```
Index: lib/web/mage/collapsible.js
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- lib/web/mage/collapsible.js (revision 7ade7283f9b19976781dd039f15f75cf04716b66)
+++ lib/web/mage/collapsible.js (revision 3df55dc134678c0eddfd83f158a902420e5dacc6)
@@ -517,9 +517,9 @@
                 'aria-hidden': 'false'
             });

-            this.element.trigger('dimensionsChanged', {
+            /*this.element.trigger('dimensionsChanged', {
                 opened: true
-            });
+            });*/
         },

         /**
```

then import it with patch command

**patch < revert_scrolltop.patch**

clear cache and run

```
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update for version 2.3.5**

As per this pr/issue,
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/23862/files

now it is already embedded and fixed within magento core code itself.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @shashank we are facing same issue on our Magento2.3.5 P2 version can u help me?

Comment: Hi, just change in collapsible library as suggested in above pr and it will be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

override and comment the below js code in collapsible.js

this.element.trigger('dimensionsChanged', {
                opened: true
           });

this was worked for me....