# Magento 2 Product page disable tabs scrolling

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to disable those tab click scroll down. when clicking on any tab I don't want to scroll on its content

[image]

Comment: follow this link:-  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293437/magento-2-3-3-tab-jumping-on-top

Answer (score 1):

My temporary solution was changing _scrollToTopIfVisible function in this file

\lib\web\mage\collapsible.js

```
From

        _scrollToTopIfVisible: function (elem) {
            if (!this._isElementOutOfViewport(elem)) {
                elem.scrollIntoView();
            }
        },
to

        _scrollToTopIfVisible: function (elem) {
            if (this._isElementOutOfViewport(elem)) {
                elem.scrollIntoView();
            }
        },
```

If anyone has other soluation please share

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to create a mixin to overrule the part which makes it scroll.

```
define([
    'jquery',
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {
        $.widget('mage.collapsible', target, {
            _create: function () {
                this.storage = $.localStorage;
                this.icons = false;

                if (typeof this.options.icons === 'string') {
                    this.options.icons = JSON.parse(this.options.icons);
                }

                this._processPanels();
                this._processState();
                this._refresh();

                if (this.options.icons.header && this.options.icons.activeHeader) {
                    this._createIcons();
                    this.icons = true;
                }

                // Removed block which make scroll to top

                this._bind('click');
                this._trigger('created');
            }
        });

        return $.mage.collapsible;
    };
});
```

I made a feature request to make this configurable/optional. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/38382